# Copy VM image to a blob storage

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to copy a VM image to a blob storage.
The image is located on Azure (Home > Images). This image doesn't have "Source blob URI".

I created a new blob storage and under it, I created a container.
Then when I go to my container, it seems that I can upload an image from my local system - but I need to upload an image which is located on Azure (Home > Images).

Someone told me that I can use `azcopy` command, and I found this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs

but it seems that with this `azcopy` command you can **only** upload an image from the **local system**, and not an image which is located on Azure.

Does anybody know how I can copy this image to my blob storage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way you could store that image in blobs would be to create a VM from that image, then download its VHD([tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json)) to store it in Blob storage/local system before doing any customization.

Comment: Thanks, but maybe you meant to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/download-vhd ?